# binding to service variable, doesnt refresh (service changes the var frequently)

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

In my Service i have the vars i want to display and the getters for it:

```
var docsLoaded = 0;
var docsToLoad = null;

pouchService.getDocsLoaded = function () {
    return docsLoaded;
};
pouchService.getDocsToLoad = function () {
    return docsToLoad;
};
```

While the service is syncing, i want to count the synced docs

```
pouchService.syncNow = function () {

    var foundLastSeq = false;
    docsLoaded = 0;
    docsToLoad = null;

    remoteDB.info().then(function (remoteInfo) {

        function findOutDiff(localPosition) {
            docsToLoad = (remoteInfo.update_seq - localPosition) + 1;
            console.log("docs to load: " + docsToLoad);
        }

        // start Sync progress
        sync = localDB.sync(remoteDB, {live: false})
        .on('change', function (info) {
            console.log('AI change: ');
            console.log(info);
            if (info.direction === 'pull') {
                if (foundLastSeq === false) {
                    foundLastSeq = true;
                    findOutDiff(info.change.last_seq);
                }
            }
            console.log(docsLoaded + " from " + docsToLoad);
            docsLoaded++;
          })
```

In my HTML i want to display the progress like this:

```
{{pouchService.getDocsLoaded()}} from {{pouchService.getDocsToLoad()}}
```

Now i get sometimes a value from getDocsLoaded, but mostly its zero. When I cancel the Syncprogress i get the value where it's stopped.

So i get the value before it really starts and when it's over, but i want it during the sync progress. (on the console my my progressinfos are working as expected)

Any ideas?

Comment: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html helped me

Comment: oh my god =) thank you so much! i already thought about apply sometimes, but didn't now where to call it and if this is really the problem. for others: cause `counter++` is in a `service` and there is no scope just use rootscope.apply instead.

Comment: I should post it as an answer!

Comment: then go ahed =) i will acceppt it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in applying scope. Jim wrote a nice article about this problem:

[jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function () {
   docsLoaded++;
});
```